# how to connect to firebird DB on android

Tags: java, android, firebird

I need to connect my android application to my firebird DB

do someone knows how to do this?

please write the code!

Comment: "please write the code!". Don't you want some coffee and cookies also?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not particularly familiar with Firebird, but my guess is the best approach would be to use a web service of some sort (RESTful?) which allows your Android client to communicate with the database. This is the solution that is typically used for most apps since you can't connect directly to the database from Android. It's also good from a design standpoint because your application does not depend on the underlying database itself, but rather the web service which acts as a mediator, meaning you can swap database implementations without impacting your client.

Answer (score 2):

Since [Jaybird](http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/jdbc-driver/) (Firebird JDBC driver) doesn't support Android, you need something more "hackish". Commercial solution would be using midware, eg RemObjects DataAbstract supports Android (pre-order/beta stage) and Firebird: http://www.remobjects.com/da/java.aspx

Comment: We have no plans to support Android with Jaybird. A quick investigation showed that it would probably require a significant rewrite to work around some of the classes not available in Android. It is probably also more performant and secure to use a middleware implementation as suggested in this answer and the answer of @TylerTreat

Comment: Changed answer to reflect Mark Rotteveel's comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this Jaybird port for Android:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/androidjaybird