# How to connect My Android app with Firebird database via JDBC(jaybird)

Tags: android, firebird2.5, jaybird

I want to connect My Android app to Firebird database using JDBC or Jaybird.I am able to connect it with in JAVA but in android i can't able. so please give me suggestion or idea about it.

Is there any additional Api add into Android App?

Thanks In Adavanced.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853845/how-to-connect-firebird-db-with-qt

Comment: http://blog.cincura.net/232132-connecting-from-android-to-firebird/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to connect to firebird DB on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473779/how-to-connect-to-firebird-db-on-android)

Answer (score 1):

In general, you should not use JDBC drivers from Android. Using JDBC from an Android device will be slow and insecure. If you want to connect an Android application to a database, you should write a rest service (eg in Java) that talks to your database, and make your Android application talk to that rest service. It will usually perform better, and is easier to secure than direct database access.

There is a separate port for android of the Jaybird JDBC driver. You can find it on http://sourceforge.net/projects/androidjaybird/ However, this port hasn't been updated for a few years and it seems to have been abandoned.

Comment: @user2361868 "not work for me" is insufficient information, you might want to consider asking a new question that includes code and a clear description of your problem.